# How to pronounce and detect 'd

Tags: pronouns

Could someone show me how to pronounce it and detect it when hearing

- I'd
- You'd
- he'd
- it'd
- we'd
- they'd

Comment: You can listen to all of them at https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/

Comment: @AliE many thanks

Comment: You would  detect it by hearing the 'd' sound!

Comment: /aɪd/, /ju:d/, /hi:d/, /ɪtəd/, /wi:d/, /ðeɪd/

Comment: @AndyBonner thank you very much. Could you make it as an answer?

Comment: @KateBunting Very often listener's brains infer the 'd' sound rather than actually hearing it (in toto).

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, it might be hard or even impossible to hear. Certain accents or habits of speech might soften or elide the "d" sound. Sometimes the only thing to do is to perceive the overall meaning, and realize from context what word is said. For instance, if you hear "If I's you, I gi'ou'a here," you extrapolate "If I was you, I'd get out of here." This is a challenge in learning a language. I find, as a Spanish learner, that I have a harder time understanding regional accents that I have less experience with. The only help for it is time and experience, and asking speakers to repeat themselves more slowly.